# Class in Python error

Tags: python

Below is the test cases and after that is my code

What I need is to correct is my error within self.teach. In the test cases below, my code states  " meow meow says meowpurr" when the correct one is " meow meow says meow and purr".
The other test cases are correct.

```
     #test cases    
meow_meow = Tamagotchi("meow meow")
meow_meow.teach("meow")
meow_meow.play()
>>>>"meow meow says meow"
meow_meow.teach("purr")
meow_meow.teach("meow")
meow_meow.play()
>>>>'meow meow says meow and purr'  #My own code state " meow meow says meowpurr"
```

Using my code:

```
class Tamagotchi(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.words = str(self.name) + " says "
        #check alive, dead within all the methods
        self.alive = True

   #trouble portion
   def teach(self, *words):
        if self.alive == False:
            self.words = self.name + " is pining for the fjords"
            return self.words
        else:
            listing = []
            for word in words:
                listing.append(str(word))
            B = " and ".join(listing)
            self.words += B


    def play(self):
        return self.words
    def kill(self):
        if self.alive == True:
            self.words = self.name + " is pining for the fjords"
            self.alive = False
            return self.name + " killed"
        else:
            return self.name + " is pining for the fjords"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store `words` as a string; store it as a list instead and only join the list with `' and '` when running `.play()`; this is also where you'd test if your tamagotchi is still alive:

```
class Tamagotchi(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.words = []
        self.alive = True

    def teach(self, *words):
        self.words.extend(words)    

    def kill(self):
        self.alive = False

    def play(self):
        if self.alive:
            return '{} says {}'.format(self.name, ' and '.join(self.words))
        else:
            return '{} is pining for the fjords'.format(self.name)
```

Your test cases don't seem to need `Tamagotchi.teach()` and `Tamagotchi.kill()` to return anything.